# "This message is shown once a day"

Tags: command-line, system-installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCom.png)Installed ubuntu and after successfully creating user name and password , it reflects few lines as in image. What does it mean?

Comment: Your question is why there is no Graphical User Interface, right? Does "startx" command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file `/etc/motd` (where MOTD stands for "Message of the Day") where the systems administrator can enter a message, which then is shown to all users when they login for the first time of the day. Remember that Linux is a multi-user operating system.

Obviously, if you are the only user of the system, that is not very useful. However, the MOTD system has been in use since the very start of Unix.

If you don't want to see the message any longer, create the file `.hushlogin` by entering this command

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```